# How can I make bixby call someone by my choice?

Tags: android, bixby, samsung-galaxy

I saw the Bixby on-device testing and wanted to create a code from a sample, that can call my mom for example.

I tried doing it myself, but it obviously ended up full of mistakes and stupid things done on the wrong place. Can someone help?